# Remove SVN from a directory and replace with newer SVN

Tags: svn, migration, visualsvn-server

So, I have a web server that has an *old* SVN client installation (as in lots of .svn directories that had been corrupted, never worked, files had to be updated manually). I now have a shiny new svn server(fresh install of visualsvn). However, my old webserver still has the old client and the old structure and the old settings.

How do I update it to use the new SVN server for the files via an svn up command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new server contains the stuff you want to use completely, meaning that there isn't anything in the old working directory that you need to commit, the best method is to rename the old top level directory to something like website-old, and then do a fresh virgin checkout of the new svn repo.

It *is* possible to change where your checkout points to if you need to commit something. For this one uses the **relocate** command, as such:

```
svn relocate svn+ssh://new-svn-server/path/to/repo/trunk/
```